# unable to upload html pages via filezilla in Plone

Tags: plone

I have connected to my Plone site by using filezilla on opensuse, a linux OS. I am now able to transer folders and files to my site. For some reason, there is a problem with htm or html files. All the files, folders, and pdf files are being transferred with the directory structure. htm or html files are not being transported. Is there something we should enable on the server in the plone site?. Please let me know when time permits. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. You just need to add the extensions on the ZMI interface in site settings in content type registry.